# What's the correct logic fix to get this binary tree delete method working properly?

Tags: ruby, recursion, binary-tree

I'm trying to write a method to delete a value from within a binary tree. However I'm failing with my logic for the case of deleting a node where it has two children. I'm using the 'replace deleted node with lowest value from the right tree approach', but I'm having problems retaining the correct child node pointers that I want to from the deleted node. Can anybody point me in the right direction with getting this working correctly, and any general suggestions for better code welcomed. Thanks in advance.

***Node#delete()***

```
  def delete(root, value)
    if root == nil
      return root
    elsif value < root.value
      root.left = delete(root.left, value)
    elsif value > root.value
      root.right = delete(root.right, value)
    else root.value == value 
      puts 'must have found the value'
      # case 1 - no children, just delete
      if root.left.nil? && root.right.nil?
        root = nil  
      # case 2 - one child, just delete and replace with child
      elsif root.left.nil?
        root = root.right
      elsif root.right.nil?
        root = root.left
      # case 3 - 2 children, find min value in right subtree and replace with this
      else
        left_node = root.left
        root = min_value(root.right)
        root.left = left_node
      end
    end
    return root
  end
```

**Contextual code:**

***Node class:***

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :left, :right
  
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
    @left = nil
    @right = nil
  end

  def self.build_balanced_tree(array)
    ... (accurately builds a balance binary tree - ommited for brevity)
  end
end
```

***Tree class***

```
class Tree
  attr_reader :root

  def initialize(array)
    @root = Node.build_balanced_tree(array)
  end
  
  def self.build_balanced_tree(array)
    tree = Tree.new(array)
    return tree
  end

  def min_value(root)
    current = root
    current = current.left until current.left.nil?
    return current
  end

  def nice_print(node, prefix = '', is_left = true)
    nice_print(node.right, "#{prefix}#{is_left ? '│   ' : '    '}", false) if node.right
    puts "#{prefix}#{is_left ? '└── ' : '┌── ' }#{node.value}"
    nice_print(node.left, "#{prefix}#{is_left ? '    ' : '│   '}", true) if node.left
  end
end
```

***Script***

```
  array = [83, 65, 99, 36, 7, 90, 25, 95, 68, 39, 96, 13, 75, 89, 2]
  tree = Tree.build_balanced_tree(array)
  tree.nice_print(tree.root)
  tree.delete(tree.root, 25)
  tree.nice_print(tree.root)
```

Comment: Your delete algorithm assumes that your tree is a binary **search** tree, but it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delete algorithm assumes that your tree is a binary search tree, but it isn't. And so the algorithm goes to the wrong subtree and doesn't find the value to delete. The `build_balanced_tree` inserts nodes such that the inorder traversal corresponds to the given array order. So either you must feed it a sorted array, or the values should be inserted one by one according to the BST insertion algorithm.

The case #3 lacks the correct `return` statement: you should return the right child of the original `root` (before it got reassigned). So change this code:

```
    left_node = root.left
    root = min_value(root.right)
    root.left = left_node
```

to:

```
    min_value(root.right).left = root.left
    return root.right
```

#### Some other remarks

It is not so elegant that the main code has to pass `root` as argument to many of the methods. I would move those methods to the `Node` class, and create small wrapper methods on the `Tree` class that call those methods on the root node. This way the main program does not have to pass that root argument.

### Code

With some other small changes, the code could look like this, which uses the BST insertion algorithm (I left out the `build_balanced_tree` method):

```
class Node
  attr_accessor :value, :left, :right
  
  def initialize(value)
    @value = value
    @left = nil
    @right = nil
  end

  def insert(value)
    if value < @value
      @left = @left ? @left.insert(value) : Node.new(value)
    elsif value > @value 
      @right = @right ? @right.insert(value) : Node.new(value)
    end
    return self
  end

  def delete(value)
    if value < @value
      @left = @left&.delete(value)
    elsif value > @value
      @right = @right&.delete(value)
    else
      puts 'must have found the value'
      # case 1 - no children, just delete
      return if @left.nil? && @right.nil?
      # case 2 - one child, just delete and replace with child
      return @right if @left.nil?
      return @left  if @right.nil?
      # case 3 - 2 children, find min value in right subtree and replace with this
      @right.min_value().left = @left
      return @right
    end
    return self
  end

  def min_value()
    current = self
    current = current.left until current.left.nil?
    return current
  end

  def nice_print(prefix = '', is_left = true)
    @right&.nice_print("#{prefix}#{is_left ? '│   ' : '    '}", false)
    puts "#{prefix}#{is_left ? '└── ' : '┌── ' }#{@value}"
    @left&.nice_print("#{prefix}#{is_left ? '    ' : '│   '}", true)
  end
      
end

class Tree
  attr_reader :root

  def initialize(array)
    @root = nil
    array.each { |n| insert(n) }
  end

  def insert(value)
    @root = @root ? @root.insert(value) : Node.new(value)
  end

  def delete(value)
    @root = @root&.delete(value)
  end

  def nice_print()
    @root&.nice_print()
  end

end



array = [83, 65, 99, 36, 7, 90, 25, 95, 68, 39, 96, 13, 75, 89, 2]
tree = Tree.new(array)
tree.nice_print()
tree.delete(7) 
tree.nice_print()
```

Comment: Thanks @trincot, very helpful, digesting now .